# How to see if email daemon is running on another server?

Tags: server, email

I have a server with Ubuntu 14.04LTS. I am sending email from Ubuntu to email.test.com and then to my Windows PC account with Outlook, but I changed the domain for this post to test.com. The email sends and I have no errors in my SMTP log but the emails are not getting to my PC account.

I can ping email.test.com but that only tells me the physical machine is running. How can I tell if the email server is running if there are no errors in my SMTP log?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to see if an email server is running.

First (read `man nmap`), and do:

```
nmap -sT -p25 --version-all email.test.com
```

Or use `telnet` (of course, read `man

telnet`), and do:

```
telnet email.test.com 25
```

In both cases, the "`25`" specifies the traditional TCP port that email servers listen to.

```
$ grep smtp /etc/services
smtp        25/tcp      mai
```

l

Comment: Thanks. The process I need is a batch process, so I can't use telnet. I'll try nmap though.